# Send form email to a REST service using JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

How to Send form email to a REST service using JSON

I´m trying so:

```
// Send Mail
$('#btn_send').click(function() {

    //  Data object contact
    this.name = $('#inputnome').val();
    this.email = $('#inputemail').val();
    this.subject = $('#inputassunto').val();
    this.message = $('#textareamsg').val();
    this.toJsonString = function() {
        return JSON.stringify(this);
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/MailWS",
        data: contact.toJsonString(),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
            alert(status.toString());
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status) {
            alert(status.toString());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm assuming, it's not working, but can you tell us a bit more? For example, is onclick function called, or is the WS called?

Comment: Why are you using `this` to assign variables to? Try adding each of the input field to an array and stringify that array.

Comment: **Bas Wildeboer**  and what would be the correct way to get the fields of the form for JSON

Comment: **user2793390**   
My button... 
<button id="btn_send" type="submit" data-theme="a" data-mini="true" data-icon="check">Enviar</button>

The function ... not called automatically when clicked on the button???

Comment: I used the example

http://www.lm-tech.it/Blog/post/2013/05/08/How-to-consume-a-RESTful-service-using-jQuery.aspx

Comment: @RobsonFagundes I think you're not binding onclick action to your element. see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're not binding onclick action to your button. Try enclosing your whole javascript in `$( document ).ready(function() {});` or do something like this which is cleaner.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#btn_send').click(function() {
    sendEmail();//
  });
});

function sendEmail(){

  var valuesArr = new Array();
  valuesArr.push($('#inputnome').val());
  valuesArr.push($('#inputemail').val());
  valuesArr.push($('#inputassunto').val());
  valuesArr.push($('#textareamsg').val());

  var jsonText = JSON.stringify(valuesArr);
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/MailWS",
      data: jsonText,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
          alert(status.toString());
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, status) {
          alert(status.toString());
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm trying

`  // listner function send mail
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#btn_send').click(function() {
                    sendEmail();//
                });
            });

            // Send Mail
            function sendEmail() {
                  ...
                };

                $.ajax({
                  ...
                    success: ...
                       ...
                    },
                    error: ...
                       ...
                    }
                });
            }`
My JSON Data Object is correct???

Comment: @RobsonFagundes Is the sendMail() function called now? Is the service called? To answer your question about valid JSON, copy the output you get and validate it - http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: @RobsonFagundes I also updated my answer to address Bas' suggestion/concern.

Comment: but still need to call my RESTFul
so http://localhost:8080/AppRobsonFagundesWS/MailWS/name/1/email/2/subject/3/message/4/